# Fetching rows in SQL Column

Tags: php, mysql

Hello Stackoverflow community.
I trying fetch Column in SQL Table that create new 'object' on page.
Data is in the same column and i need fetch it separetly by lines.

NOTE: \n = brand for break line

\zn = brand for insert "delete button"

My code:

```
<?php 
            $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "blahblah", "blahbla_database");
            $userglobal = $w['user']['username']; // this get username of logged user
            $sql = "SELECT emails FROM users WHERE (`username` = '{$userglobal}')";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);
                     if($result->num_rows > 0) {
                           while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                              if ($row["emails"] !== NULL) {
                              echo "<div class='list-group'>";
                              echo "<a href='./mail' target='_blank' class='list-group-item list-group-item-action'>";
                              $mail_showed = nl2br($row["emails"]);
                              $mail_showed = str_replace('\n', "<br />", $mail_showed);
                              $mail_showed = str_replace('\zn', "", $mail_showed);

                              echo $mail_showed;
                              echo "<span class='badge badge-primary badge-pill'>".CountNewMails($mail_var)."</span></a>"; // Get new mails in number then show it
                              echo "</div>";
                            } else { echo "<h5 class='text-center'>".$w['user']['username']." You dont have yet mail</h5>";}
                           }
                       }
              ?>
```

Result is this:

```
<div class='list-group'>
<a href='./mail' target='_blank' class='list-group-item list-group-item-action'>usermail@domain.com
<span class='badge badge-primary badge-pill'>14</span></a>
</div>
```

Problem:
When in column is more than 1 mail address the mail is showed as:

```
<div class='list-group'>
    <a href='./mail' target='_blank' class='list-group-item list-group-item-action'>usermail@domain.com<br>2mail@domain.com
    <span class='badge badge-primary badge-pill'>14</span></a>
</div>
```

What i need:

```
 <div class='list-group'>
        <a href='./mail' target='_blank' class='list-group-item list-group-item-action'>usermail@domain.com
        <span class='badge badge-primary badge-pill'>14</span></a>
       <a href='./mail' target='_blank' class='list-group-item list-group--item-action'>2mail@domain.com
        <span class='badge badge-primary badge-pill'>99</span></a>

    </div>
```

Comment: Hmm, at first glance everything is fine. But what does your query return if you execute it in mysql directly?

Comment: Are you storing more than one email address inside one field? That's a design mistake in your database.

Comment: `$emails = explode($mail_showed,'<br />');` and run `foreach($emails as $value){ /*do something here*/ }`   and don't store multiple emails in same column instead normalize it

Comment: @ADyson Yep, you're right. I create new table for this.. **SOLVED**